# Vim incremental search next result

Tags: vim, incremental-search

I have **incsearch** and **hlsearch** enabled

So I hit `/` to enter search mode.

Then I type text I want to search for and it finds the first occurrence of the text I typed.

Then I want to jump to next occurrence of the text I typed without exiting search mode so that I could refine my search text later without having to exit to normal mode, then hitting `n` and then going back to search mode by hitting `/` again.

If this is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best thing that I can find that you can do is the following:

Search for your pattern using /blah

Then, hit n or ? until you see what's out there...

Then go back to / and press CTRL-r /

this will bring back the last pattern that you searched for, so you can continue entering more text there...

I'm sure you can remap that combination to some key so that you can quickly go back to the search with the pattern already entered.

Comment: when you get back into the search mode, you can scroll through your history buy just hitting "up" button.

Comment: or use `q/` to go to the search history window.

Comment: @ezdazuzena `<C-p>` is much easier to type than `<Up>`.

Comment: @ZyX: Isn't this just auto-complete?

Answer (score 8):

I've found a way thanks to **bwana147** from #vim irc channel on freenode.net

```
:cnoremap <c-n> <CR>n/<c-p>
```

After that typing text in **search mode** and then hitting ctrl-n goes to next occurrence of that text without exiting **search mode**

Comment: since i can't accept my answer i'll accept vmpstr which is basicly explanation of the same technique used in this cmap combo

Comment: I've improved this a bit (using `cnoremap` and `<c-g>`, because I have mapped <c-p>/<c-n> for completion already): `:cnoremap <c-g> <CR>n/<c-p>`.
Unfortunately this attempt adds entries to the jumplist for each step, which the intermediate steps before `<CR>` in `incsearch mode` do not so.

Answer (score 3):

***I have `incsearch` and `hlsearch` enabled. So I hit `/` to enter search mode. Then I type text which I want to search for and it finds the first occurrence.***

Okey so far ...

Here, I can't quite understand what you're asking.

***Then I want to jump to next occurrence of the text I typed without exiting search mode***

This is done by pressing `n`

*so that I could refine my search text later without having to exit to normal mode, then hitting **n** and then going back to search mode by hitting `/` again.*

You got me lost here ... isn't this behaviour exactly what `incsearch` enables you?

Comment: In incsearch mode, as you search it will go to the location of the next match, what he wishes to do is without having to press enter & press 'n', find some way to jump to that next match without ever leaving the search mode.

Comment: @DhruvaSagar - I think I understand; more emacs behaviour, so to speak.

Comment: @Idigas well I don't know about that, but I don't think it's really possible to achieve what he wants...

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl-g or Ctrl-t for incremental search. When you want to search something hit /some, then hit Ctrl-t this will jump the cursor to first some, but you stay in search mode, you can add "thing" to search, and search pattern will be /something.