# Vim incremental search

Tags: linux, eclipse, vim, putty

I'm using putty on a Linux machine. My usual method for searching in vi is entering the slash <kbd>/</kbd>, then my search string, enter, then go through all the matches by <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>.

I was wondering if vi had a feature like Eclipse's Incremental Search (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>), wherein as I type, it jumps to the next logical match. I think one of my office mates used to do it but I'm not sure.

Comment: For the record, incremental search is covered by vimtutor. Anybody who is at least half-serious about using Vim efficiently should really start their Vim life by a vimtutor session. After all, it only takes half an hour or so.

Comment: Expected to recall a feature presented at beginning of vimlife? That's the exact time you wouldn't memory-bank a non-critical feature

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you're using `vim` (and who isn't nowadays), you can enable incremental search with:

```
:set incsearch
```

Then just use the regular search command `/` and it will move the highlight as you add characters to the search string.

I also like `hlsearch` as well since it highlights all found items (once the search command is done) for easy viewing.

Comment: how do you cycle through the results? Say I type `/app` and I have the words `app` and `apple`, how do I cycle through the results?

Comment: @J86: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195010/vim-incremental-search-next-result.

Comment: How would you use `hlsearch` with `incsearch`, but prevent Vim from jumping to the first result?

Comment: @Felix, you should be asking a *question* about that rather than leaving a comment. The entire SO swarm will see the former, very few people will see (and act on) the latter. In any case, I'm not sure I understand. The whole point of `incsearch` is to jump to the first match depending on what you're typing in. If you didn't want to do that, you would disable `incsearch`, surely?

Comment: Definitely worth adding both  `incsearch` and `hlsearch` to .vimrc.